# webpack - hot reload on linked node_module change

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, npm-link

In my local environment, I have my primary project (A) which links to another project/local library (B) via npm link.

When I make updates to Project B, I have to run a build and then re-assert the link.  After this completes, I then have to re-compile Project A via webpack by making a change to a file in Project A.

Project B is registered via global.  Is there a way for Webpack to hot-reload on detection of a global package change?

Comment: Does your module has the `accept` mentioned [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement.html)?